# Исследование

Tags: морфология

Скажите, можно ли определить частеречную принадлежность вводных слов?можно ли на этом материале написать исследовательскую работу?

Answer (score 2):

[Вводные слова](http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r1_2_10)

> По своей грамматической соотнесённости вводные слова и конструкции могут восходить к различным частям речи и различным грамматическим формам:
>
> **существительные в различных падежах с предлогами и без предлогов**;
>
> Без сомнения, на радость, к счастью и др.
>
> **прилагательные в краткой форме**, в различных падежах, в превосходной степени;
>
> Право, виноват, главное, в общем, самое главное, самое меньшее.
>
> **местоимения в косвенных падежах с предлогами**;
>
> Кроме того, к тому же, между тем.
>
> **наречия в положительной или сравнительной степени**;
>
> Бесспорно, конечно, вероятно, короче, вернее.
>
> **глаголы** в различных формах изъявительного или повелительного наклонения;
>
> Думаю, веришь ли, казалось, говорят, вообрази, помилуй.
>
> **инфинитив или сочетание с инфинитивом**;
>
> Видать, знать, признаться, смешно сказать.
>
> **сочетания с деепричастиями**;
>
> Правду говоря, короче говоря, грубо выражаясь.
>
> двусоставные предложения с подлежащим – личным местоимением и сказуемым – глаголом со значением волеизъявления, говорения, мысли и др.;
>
> Сколько я помню, я часто думаю.
> безличные предложения;
>
> Ей мнилось, нам всем хорошо помнится.
> неопределённо-личные предложения.
>
> Так думали о нём, как обычно говорили о нём.
>
> Именно поэтому необходимо различать вводные слова и омонимичные им формы и конструкции.

Я думаю, можно написать очень дельное исследование на тему вводных слов, было бы желание!

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: А вводное слово - это вроде бы синтаксическая функция? Вводным словом мы называем   слово (или словосочетание), входящее в состав предложения, но не вступающее с его членами в синтаксическую связь. В качестве вводного слова могут выступать различные части речи.